# Trying to change text of a label to a variable on button click but can't access the class

Tags: java, variables, button, text

I've been trying for a while to change the text of a label to a variable on button click but can't access the class. When the button is pressed it's supposed to change the text of iscoreTotal to variable clicks and it updates every time but I can't figure how to access the class. I'm trying to access the class start where the label is created so I can change it in the Circle class on button click

```
package stackover;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PaintFrame extends JFrame {

// Variables for defining size and position of the circle

public static int iCircleSize() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
}

public static int iCirclePosX() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 450 + 100);
}

public static int iCirclePosY() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 450 + 100);
}

public static int iclicks = 0;

private static JPanel content = new JPanel();
private PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();

public PaintFrame() {
    getContentPane().add(content);
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content.add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PaintFrame();
    PaintFrame.start();
}

public static void start() {
    int istartPosX = iCirclePosX();
    int istartPosY = iCirclePosY();
    PaintPanel board = new PaintPanel();
    board.add(new Circle(istartPosX, istartPosY, new Dimension(100, 100)));
    board.add(new Circle(istartPosX, istartPosY, new Dimension(100, 100)));
    board.add(new Circle(istartPosX, istartPosY, new Dimension(100, 100)));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Oscar's Aim Trainer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(650, 650);
    frame.setContentPane(board);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    board.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel iscoreTotal = new JLabel("0");
    panel.add(iscoreTotal);
    iscoreTotal.setBounds(50, 350, 100, 35);
    iscoreTotal.setBackground(Color.black);
    iscoreTotal.setForeground(Color.black);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    }
}

class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
PaintPanel() {
    super(null);
}
}

class Circle extends JComponent {

Circle(int x, int y, Dimension size) {
    setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), size));
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            move();
            System.out.println("Clicked, " + getBounds());
            PaintFrame.iclicks++;
            System.out.println(+PaintFrame.iclicks);
            if (PaintFrame.iclicks == 10) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
    });
}

private void move() {

    int iSize = PaintFrame.iCircleSize();
    int istartPosX = PaintFrame.iCirclePosX();
    int istartPosY = PaintFrame.iCirclePosY();
    setLocation(new Point(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(istartPosX),
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(istartPosY)

    ));
    setSize(iSize + 50, iSize + 50);
}

@Override

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    // This code accounts for the shape of the object being placed
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference of the label so you can change its text. So we need to have the reference of the label in the circle class.
First, you need to move your lable variable into the class scope. Then you need some way to reference your class PaintFrame. I did it with a static varible of the class called instance. But you could also use other ways but this one is quite nice to use.
Here is the code hope it works:

```
package stackover;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PaintFrame extends JFrame {

// Variables for defining size and position of the circle

public static int iCircleSize() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
}

public static int iCirclePosX() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 450 + 100);
}

public static int iCirclePosY() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 450 + 100);
}

public static int iclicks = 0;

private static JPanel content = new JPanel();
private PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();

public PaintFrame() {
    getContentPane().add(content);
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content.add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PaintFrame();
    PaintFrame.start();
}

public static PaintFrame instance; //Here is the static reference of the class. 
public JLabel iscoreTotal; // Here is the public reference of your label.

public static void start() {
    instance = this; // Here we assing the static refernec the current context.

    int istartPosX = iCirclePosX();
    int istartPosY = iCirclePosY();
    PaintPanel board = new PaintPanel();
    board.add(new Circle(istartPosX, istartPosY, new Dimension(100, 100)));
    board.add(new Circle(istartPosX, istartPosY, new Dimension(100, 100)));
    board.add(new Circle(istartPosX, istartPosY, new Dimension(100, 100)));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Oscar's Aim Trainer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(650, 650);
    frame.setContentPane(board);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    board.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

// now we only assing iscoreTotal not decalre it because we already did that.
    iscoreTotal = new JLabel("0"); 
    panel.add(iscoreTotal);
    iscoreTotal.setBounds(50, 350, 100, 35);
    iscoreTotal.setBackground(Color.black);
    iscoreTotal.setForeground(Color.black);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    }
}

class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
PaintPanel() {
    super(null);
}
}

class Circle extends JComponent {

Circle(int x, int y, Dimension size) {
    setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), size));
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            move();
            System.out.println("Clicked, " + getBounds());
            PaintFrame.iclicks++;
            System.out.println(+PaintFrame.iclicks);

            // now you can assing the click varibel to you lable.
            PaintFrame.instance.iscoreTotal.text = PaintFrame.iclicks; 

            if (PaintFrame.iclicks == 10) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
    });
}

private void move() {

    int iSize = PaintFrame.iCircleSize();
    int istartPosX = PaintFrame.iCirclePosX();
    int istartPosY = PaintFrame.iCirclePosY();
    setLocation(new Point(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(istartPosX),
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(istartPosY)

    ));
    setSize(iSize + 50, iSize + 50);
}

@Override

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    // This code accounts for the shape of the object being placed
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

;
}
```